Light curves for Chandra
I am working with Chandra data. I only have the corrected PI files for the sources. Is there a way to plot the light curve from this PI file. I wanted to extract the color magnitude ultimately.

PI files, or more commonly PHA files, are higher level data products derived by binning the (cleaned) event list by the registered PI/PHA channel of each event, which should correspond to their energy. Therefore, PHA/PI files contain the spectra of a given source.
This binning, however, removes the information when each event was detected, which makes it impossible to generate a light-curve from a PI/PHA file.
If you want the light-curve you have to go back to the event-list and perform a binning not by PI/PHA channel but by time (while accounting for GTI intervals).
Usually the different X-ray missions provide the necessary tools that perform these different binnings for you. In case of Chandra this would be e.g. dmextract.
Chandra provides a bunch guides how to do all that. And for anyone new to X-ray astronomy their primer is also highly recommended.
Alternatively, you can only avoid this if you already have, say, a PI-file for every time bin your are interested in. Say, a PI file for each 100s period of your observation. In that case you can get the count-rate for each PI file by first summing up all the counts in the individual spectral bins and dividing them by the total exposure time (which should be a FITS keyword in the header, or can be derived from the GTI file). Alternatively you could fit the spectrum of each PI-file and derive the flux over time, which might be physically more interesting, but also more work.

What are PI, PHA, and GTI? Pulse invariant (whatever that is), pulse height analyzer (whatever that is), and good time interval (whatever that is)?

PI & PHA is explained the the X-ray Data Primer that is linked above and Good Time Intervals (GTIs) just tell you when your detector was switched on and actually receptive to incoming photons.
